# Can I change RTSP URI with ONVIF?

Tags: streaming, rtsp, onvif

I am working on a IP cam job. I want to change my RTSP URI. I'm using ONVIF and I get RTSP adress with GetStreamURI SOAP REQUEST. But I can't change this adress. For example my adress is "rtsp://localhost/channel2" but I want change it "rtsp://localhost/mystreamstring" . So can I do it with ONVIF? Or can I create another stream profile like this?

Comment: Anybody has any answer?

Answer (score 0):

The ONVIF standard does not concern change the RTSP url for an onvif profile. So the answer is, you can not. But if you want to provide video stream by custom url you can use some Video Streaming Server like Unreal.